# Number guessing game with C# console

Tags: c#, console

I need to make a number guessing game in C#. The program will keep the number and the user will find the number. I made the game, but what is required of me is that the guessed number is between the smallest and the largest two numbers. In short, the user will enter a small and large number, and the computer will choose a number between these two numbers. The application I made is between zero and one hundred. Below are the codes I made. I would be glad if you help.

```
int sayi=0,tahmin=0,min=0,max=100,sayac=0;
Random Rnd = new Random();
sayi =Convert .ToInt32 ( Rnd.Next(0, 100));
Console.Write("0-100 arası bir sayı giriniz  ");
do
{
    sayac++;
    tahmin = Convert.ToByte(Console.ReadLine());
    if (tahmin >sayi)
        max = tahmin;
    else
        min = tahmin;

    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} arasında sayı giriniz", min, max);
}
while (sayi!=tahmin);

Console.WriteLine("Tebrikler sayı {0}, {1} .tahminde bildiniz", sayi,sayac );
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: what exactly is your question? Does the above code do what it is supposed to do? If not: what behaviour do you expect and what do you get instead?

Comment: The code above does what it's supposed to do. It chooses numbers between 1 and 100, what I want to do is choose a number between the two entered numbers.

Comment: replace `Rnd.Next(0, 100)` by `Rnd.Next(firstNumber, secondNumber)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can prompt the use for the lowest and largest range of the number before the user start to guess:

```
Console.Write("Enter the minimum range: ");
int Smallest = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Enter the maximum range: ");
int Largest = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Then you can store those range on your `Rnd.Next()` method

```
sayi = Convert.ToInt32(Rnd.Next(Smallest, Largest));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thats want i need.

Comment: @FurkanUğurlu thanks, you can upvote it then make it the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int RandomNumber = rnd.Next(Min, Max);
```